# Javascript array lexial reference error in code

Tags: javascript

1

```
let workdone = ["user" , name , address , info];

alert( workdone[0] );
```

2

```
let fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Plum"];

alert( fruits[0] );
```

the second code is working but the first one is not, is showing

> ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration

why??

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Andreas wouldn't he just get "whatever is not defined" in that case? Please show more of the code, how are these variables declared ?

Comment: You should show us more from your code. Are the `name`, `adress` and and `info` variables defined?